# How to correctly prepare a dataset from tfrecords for timeseries classification in tensorflow 2 using the tf. dataset api?

Tags: time-series, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets, tfrecord

I'm trying to properly return a tensorflow dataset from a TFRecordDataset so I can apply a window and batch function but I think the way I return my parsed data from the tfrecords files is causing issues as I'm met with `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'batch'`.

In a data processing step I'm preparing my tfrecords such that each file is one timeseries. each timeseries have multiple features of length timesteps and a label "column" that's just the timeseries class label repeated for every timestep. My dataset is huge so I want to avoid any pandas and numpy solutions and work with the tensorflow 2 datasets only.

I have made a toy example to reproduce my error:

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)
#2.1.0
import numpy as np

# generating dummy data and writing to file:

feature_dict = {}
feature_dict.update({ 'timesteps' : tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=range(50)))})
feature_dict.update({ 'x' : tf.train.Feature(float_list=tf.train.FloatList(value=[np.float(x) for x in range(50)]))})
feature_dict.update({ 'label' : tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=np.ones(50).astype(int)))})

example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature=feature_dict))
with tf.io.TFRecordWriter('./test.tfrecord') as writer:
    writer.write(example.SerializeToString())

# reading file:
def parse_record_function(example_proto):    
    feature_description = {}
    feature_description['timesteps'] = tf.io.FixedLenFeature([50], dtype=tf.int64)
    feature_description['x'] = tf.io.FixedLenFeature([50], dtype=tf.float32)
    feature_description['label'] = tf.io.FixedLenFeature([50], dtype=tf.int64)

    parsed_features = tf.io.parse_single_example(example_proto, feature_description)
    return parsed_features

dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filenames = './test.tfrecord')
print(dataset)
dataset = dataset.map(parse_record_function)
print(dataset)

#attempting to prepare for timeseries fails:
dataset = dataset.window(10).flat_map(lambda window: window.batch(10))
```

the last line fails. `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'batch'`. somehow the dataset is not a proper dataset but a dict type because of the parsing that takes place in `parse_record_function`. But I thought this was the correct way to read in tfrecords, atleast that's my idea after looking at the tensorflow tfrecords tutorial page: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/tfrecord#read_the_tfrecord_file

How should I either *write* my data in tfrecords files or *process* my data in `parse_record_function` in order to apply window and batch flattening?

Ultimately I want to end up with the equivalent of data in the format [batch_size, n_timesteps, n_features] to feed a timeseries classifier. Any additional suggestions on how to move forward with making this happen are also most welcome.

Comment: How did you come up with this part? flat_map(lambda window: window.batch(10) have you tried creating a map function to pass in the flat_map() instead ? as indicated here https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/TFRecordDataset#flat_map